# How to write a RNG code in Python 2.7 that writes shakespeare

Tags: python-2.7, random

For fun, I'm trying to write a code in python that associates a random number with a letter of the alphabet or punctuation mark and adds that letter to a list. I then want to have the code keep making new lists of random letters until it outputs "to be or not to be, that is the question." I then want to print that list and see how many evaluations it took. This is what I have so far.

```
from random import *

alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',',',' ','.']

sentence = []

numbers = []


def random(x):

     randval = x
     return randval


count = 0
for i in range(1000): # trying to place an upper bound on how many times to try
     for i in range(41): # the number of characters in the sentence
         randomness = random(randint(0,28)) # the number of enteries in the alphabet list
         numbers.append(randomness)     
     for i in numbers:
         count += 1
         sentence.append(alphabet[i]) 
     if sentence!=['t','o',' ','b','e',' ','o','r',' ','n','o','t',' ','t','o',' ','b','e',',',' ','t','h','a','t',' ','i','s','t','h','e',' ','q','u','e','s','t','i','o','n','.']:
         sentence = [] ### This is supposed to empty the list if it gets the wrong order, but doesn't quite do that.
     if sentence == ['t','o',' ','b','e',' ','o','r',' ','n','o','t',' ','t','o',' ','b','e',',',' ','t','h','a','t',' ','i','s','t','h','e',' ','q','u','e','s','t','i','o','n','.']:
         print sentence
         print count
         break

 new_sentence = ''.join(sentence)    
 print new_sentence
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The list size keeps blowing up instead of keeping a length of 41. suggestions?

Comment: It looks like your indentation was messed up when you pasted the code into Stack Overflow; could you please re-check that? At the moment I can see what would be a bug in the code (you using `i` for three different, apparently-nested loop variables), but I won’t be able to guess why your failsafe doesn’t work unless I can see the indentation.

Comment: You will have to wait years or more to obtain that output (with high probability).

Comment: @sascha Never say never. True, it’ll take about 10^44 years assuming 4 guesses per nanosecond (faster than most modern single-core hardware), which puts us in the [Black Hole Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe#Black_Hole_Era) or [Degenerate Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe#Degenerate_Era_2) depending on some physics we haven’t figured out. But that’s a lot shorter than “never”, which is infinite. Almost all positive numbers are larger than only 10^44.

Comment: Again, I can’t tell for sure with your indentation, but it looks like it’s because when you clear `sentence` you don’t also clear `numbers`. Why are you using two separate arrays for that instead of just appending `alphabet[randomness]` directly?

Comment: I got only 4 x 10^42 years, assuming a billion guesses per second. But yes, that's still many, many, many times longer than the current age of the universe, and well beyond any projected possibility of the human race still existing.

Comment: Your `random()` function returns its input unmodified. What is the point of that?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I came up with 2.9x10^43 years for a billion guesses per second, calculated as `29**41 / 1E9 / 3600 / 24 / 365.25`.  (A billion trials per second, 3600 seconds per hour, 24 hours per day, and 365.25 days per year on average.)